# How to use Mirr() func in from apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/Mirr.html in android?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I need to make calculation using MIRR() function at excel in Android. I found apache has the same function in [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/Mirr.html). But I don't need to make it as excel file, only value of the function. Is that possible?

Comment: Just call the [evaluate method directly](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/Mirr.html#evaluate-double:A-)?

Comment: I can't call it dirrectly, it seems I need to implementation of its library in Manifest.xml but I confuse where do I know about the version, this I mean :
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'